# Activity’s documentLaunchMode (set in Manifest) different at runtime

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My AndroidManifest.xml has one activity.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.foo.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="standard"
    android:documentLaunchMode="-----------"
  >
```

I have tried setting this activity’s `documentLaunchMode` (added in Lollipop) to each of the four possible values: `"none"` (value 0), `"intoExisting"` (value 1), `"always"` (value 2), and `"never"` (value 3). Regardless of the value I give documentLaunchMode in the AndroidManifest.xml, at runtime it is always 0.

(Values are from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#documentLaunchMode.)
I am using the following code to get the value of documentLaunchMode.

```
    int docLaunchMode = -1;
    ComponentName cn = getComponentName();
    try {
      docLaunchMode = (getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(cn, 0)).documentLaunchMode;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
      Log.d("documentLaunchMode", "Error getting ActivityInfo");
    }
    Log.d("documentLaunchMode", "documentLaunchMode: " + docLaunchMode);
```

Am I attempting to set the documentLaunchMode incorrectly?  Alternatively, am I trying to see the values at runtime incorrectly?

Comment: Same result here. Weird.